# Word for sailboat moving in a harbour

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb for the motion of a sailboat in a marina or harbour when the yacht or dinghy is solely powered by an engine, not the sails?

For example: "Peter's dinghy slowly xxxxed from its mooring in the harbour until it could set sail in the open sea".

Comment: Is it moving in or out of the harbor?

Comment: Taxiiing :)))) ...

Comment: I have heard "motor" used as a verb for this.

Comment: A boat that is being driven by a motor is said to be proceeding *under power*. So you could use *powered* although this might imply greater speed than you describe.

Answer (score 3):

The sailboat **motored** into port.

Here is an article using [motored](http://www.captainjohn.org/Boat4.html).

> A sailboat “motored” all the way around  the Great Loop will
>   undoubtedly be your most fuel efficient vessel.

Answer (score 1):

Describing slow (and usually noisy) movement with a motor:

***to chug***

(others could be *to chuff; to putter; to chuggle*)

"Peter's dinghy chugged along from its mooring until it could set sail in the open sea"

Comment: It's conventional on ELU to provide a definition and a source; you might want to add that.  Is dinghy a name for a small sailboat?

Answer (score 1):

While *maneuver* is perfectly fine for the casual boater, a more formal term would be the noun and verb **pilot**.

A [maritime pilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maritime_pilot) (can also be called a harbor pilot) is that person who safely navigates and maneuvers a vessel within a harbor, canal, or other difficult space, where knowledge of the conditions and obstacles are especially important.

Any boater might be more comfortable having someone with experience to pilot their vessel within a harbor, regardless of their own vessel size, especially where larger vessels are in transit. I might hire a local to pilot my vessel into or out of a lagoon where reefs are a concern. An operator of a vessel of any size might want to do this.

One might think that piloting under power is easier and safer than piloting while under sail. I can't imagine any pilot who would disagree, but strictly speaking, *pilot* does not distinguish between any means of power. A skilled sailor might do his piloting either way. (It can be a bit of a show when done successfully under sail and in tight spots, but it's better when it's done with someone else's boat.)